# Trigger if directory size exceeds threshold

Tags: bash, kernel, scripts, python, java

I have written a shell script to backup data to s3 and i want to trigger this shell script when ever the system storage space goes critical lets say when the system reaches 80% of its capacity. I know there are utilities like watch which monitor the system size but they are level triggers i.e. they monitor on a regular basis. What i want is an edge trigger(sort of a callback, a triggger) which activates on the above defined condition. What is the best way to write such a trigger on a debian based system. Please suggest methods in bash, C, C++, python or java.

What i meant by edge trigger is that whenever the system state is critical ie the usage is above say 80% a trigger should be generated. I dont want to poll every say 1 hr to check the state.

Lemme elaborate a bit about my use case. On every request(via get or post api) the request body is pushed to kafka. Say kafka went down then the logs are written to the system and now i have a script which rotates logs on s3 only when the systemm state is critical.

In this case as u can see the kafka wont go down quite often. Say it went down once every 6month so having a thread to check the directory size every 1 hr is just waste of resource. That is why i wanted an edge trigger.

I also came across a service known as inotify. just wondering is this the best we can do (performance wise) ?

Any help please

Thanks

Comment: yeah, unfortunately what you ask for is way above my head. I'm not familiar neither with kafka nor post/get api.Would have been nice if you provided all that info earlier

Comment: On a side note, every form of status monitoring utility employs some form of polling. Unless it's a single-shot script calles from cron.

Comment: Sorry serg for editing it late just think of api or kafka as just a service which will dump the data to some directory and i want another service to get triggered on some condition. I was thinking something like whenever we do anything on the filesystem then isnt there a hook or something which could generate a callback everytime filesystem is called to perform some action ? just a vague guess

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have periodic check, say on every restart or every Tuesday of the month, you could set up a cron job, that calls your backup script, and you could check the filesystem usage within your backup script itself. Can be done simply like so:

```
if [ $(df / --output=pcent | awk -F '%' 'NR==2{print $1}') -ge 80 ] ; 
then 
   # do something here 
fi
```

That basically  calls `df` command with output limited to percentage use and `/` filesystem , and trims the output so that only percentage is returned. If  percentage is greater or equal to 80 , it would execute whatever you place after the `# do something here`  comment.

If you want continuously running solution , here's a Python script that checks your filesystem usage every 0.25 seconds. I've written a simple wrapper function for `subprocess.check_output` , so you can use that to easily place call to your script there in form of a list of strings ( which is basically this: `['brackets', 'and' , 'quotes']`  )

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import time
import sys

def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    # function for running 
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           pass
    else:
        if stdout:
            return  stdout

fs_usage = ""

while True:
    fs_usage = run_cmd( "df / --output=pcent".split() )
    if int(fs_usage.split("\n")[1].strip().split("%")[0]) >= 80 :
        # make call to your backup script here !
        # Use list format
        run_cmd( [ 'notify-send','Hello','World'  ]  )
        sys.exit(1)
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Comment: Maybe i didnt make the question quite clear in the lemme edit and see the edited post